# Call to Controller from a href returns nothing (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, laravel

I have to logout the users from my site.
I have this in the view:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('up_sessions.destroy') }}">Logout</a>
```

in routes.php I heve this:

```
Route::resource('up_sessions','SessionsController');
```

The destroy method from SessionsController does something like

```
session()->put('key', null);
```

and at the end return `Redirect::to('Home');`

When I click on 'Logout' it send me to localhost:8000/up_sessions/%7Bup_sessions%7D
and nothing happens.
I was expecting a return to 'Home' and this is what I need, click on logout, go to controller, call  destroy method, unset the sessions keys and go back to Home.
I don't understand why the link has this last segment %7Bup_sessions%7D ...I don't have  a route for this and I don't know how to get rid of it.
Anyway, I just need to click on logout and logout for good.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

To point your route to your desire controller method use this

```
<a href="{{ action('SessionsController@destroy') }}">Logout</a>
```

Comment: I don't use Auth to authenticate the users because I have 2 forms on the same page to log in 2 kind of users and I don't know how to change the natural flow to deal with this situation. In this case, if I use your way, does the Auth method works  ?

Comment: try `<a href="{{ url('up_sessions') }}">Logout</a>`

Comment: In this case 'up_sessions' behaves like a view that shows nothing

Comment: sorry, you should use this <a href="{{ action('SessionsController@destroy') }}">Logout</a>

Comment: Problem solved with:  Route::get('/Visitors/logout','SessionsController@destroy'); Route::resource('up_sessions','SessionsController');                                             and <a href="/Visitors/logout">Logout</a>

Comment: you are hard coding the URL which is not good for future maintenance, use named route instead to point to your controller method

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/up_sessions/destroy')}}">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use link_to_action helper ti accomplish what you want. For example :

```
{!! link_to_action('SessionsController@destroy','Log out',[pramameters,...,...]) !!}
 //pass parameter if you have it
```

Then in your SessionController, you handle how it works

```
public function destroy($parameter...){
   //destroy session...
   return redirect('home');
}
```